# Playing several custom YouTube video urls with start and end time in sequence like a playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

We can set the *start* and *end* time in a youtube video like in this example and it works: https://www.youtube.com/v/97QyJve5L40&t=46s&start=83&end=106&autoplay=1

**Explanation:**

From the original youtube url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97QyJve5L40&t=46s

we just have to change 'watch?v=' to 'v/'

and append '&start=83&end=106' to the end, where the time is always in seconds.

we can also add '&autoplay=1' to the end, where 1 is for the video to autoplay and 0 is for the video to play only when we click on it to play (default).

**Question:**

What is the best way we could consider for playing several of these custom YouTube video urls, with start and end time, in sequence like a playlist? (Note that the YouTube website at the time of this writing lost the ability to set start and end time for each video in playlists.

Comment: Link to YouTube help documenting this feature's official removal from playlists, circa December 2014 "due to recurring breakages and very low usage": https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/Gipu_cCDScI and a workaround manually adjusting specific url parameters that may have worked for a few months before that: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/2LRX6mZXNU4

Comment: This is a great question. I wish my video player could accept a list of URLs formatted like the one you mentioned. [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) plays the URL, but it plays the video from beginning to end, unfortunately.

Comment: Browser extension based answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172699/305338).

Answer (score 5):

5 years ago and I can still see no good solution out there, so I have created my minimalist solution to this.

https://cytsunny.github.io/youtube-playlist/

Soure Code: https://github.com/cytsunny/youtube-playlist/

Hope Youtube will some day add this function back to their official playlist function.